# How to prevent table dump in MySQL

Tags: mysql, security

I have a security concern that is growing larger as we hire more people.

Right now everyone on our engineering team has access to at least one database. We rarely do table-specific permissions, since everyone basically works on everything. As a result, many of our engineers have SELECT privileges on tables containing valuable information.

As we grow, I have no doubt that one day we'll run into someone maliciously trying to steal our data. With MySQL, merely granting SELECT means they can dump the table out.

How exactly do we protect ourselves from something like this? Even if we log everything, it's still a case of discovering afterwards, and not preventing it in the first place.

Comment: Don't give said people access to live data? Only fake (development / anonymised) data.

Comment: Have them sign contracts which say if they try to steal data, they'll end up in court.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about programmer management, not programming.